# Call a component method before every action

Tags: yii2-advanced-app

I have a component and want to call it before every action.
So how can i call it and i need the current action name

```
 $this->actionname()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this into main.php file

```
'as beforeRequest' => [
    'class' => 'path\to\your-components' \\ api\components\mycomponent
],
```

this will call your component before on every request

To get the current action name

```
Yii::$app->request->resolve()[0]
```